# How I can use the IP address assigned to my compuer by Comcast to access it from the network

Tags: ip, internet

I used the [WhatIsMyIPAddress](http://whatismyipaddress.com) website to determine the IP assigned to my computer being connected to the Internet via Comcast. The site shows my IPV6 address as `2601:246:c001:3c41:55bc:b835:c09e:97e` 
and I can successfully ping it.

On this machine I have a application installed that works successfully being invoked locally from a browser in this way:

```
localhost:4447/TestJSP
```

How I can invoke the same app from the Internet using this IP `2601:246:c001:3c41:55bc:b835:c09e:97e` provided to my machine by Comcast?

Comment: Is this your computer IP address or your router IP address?

Comment: The minimal steps before exposing a machine as a server would be to ensure the patching is up to date, configure a firewall, publish DNS records, install a host based IDS and check the backups are up to date. Then just make sure your application is correctly configured and point a browser at it. Or did you mean that you've doen all this and the outcome was not what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a NAT in between you and Comcast, you need to port forward port 4447 to your computer's internal IP. If you have a firewall between you and Comcast, you need to allow incoming port 4447. Otherwise your application should already be live. Go to http://[2601:246:c001:3c41:55bc:b835:c09e:97e]:4447/TestJSP once you have done that.

Note: It seems at least one of the factors I mentioned is in play, as I am unable to access that URI from an IPv6-capable connection.

Comment: IPv6 doesn’t need port forwarding. It doesn’t have NAT. A more accurate description in this case would be to allow it through the firewall.

Comment: Sort of. IPv6 CAN use NAT but it's uncommon. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I’m not aware of any real deployment of IPv6 NAT. So rather than uncommon, it’s more like practically non-existent.

Comment: +1 Thanks. You have answered my question - How to use IPv6 in a URL

Answer (score 0):

Because it’s IPv6, you can just use this very IPv6 address to access it from anywhere on the world, provided no firewall blocks the connections.

Which is very likely, because a novice user wouldn’t want his “internal network” to be open to anyone. So you’ll have to look through your router’s configuration for IPv6 firewall rules.

With IPv6, there’s no NAT, so every device connected to the Internet has a public, Internet-routable IPv6 address. Your router has one, too, but it’ll be different.

Please also note that there are still many places that are not IPv6-enabled. You won’t be able to access IPv6 resources from there.

*Update*: After looking at the page you used, it doesn’t look so sophisticated. Even though you (most likely) also have IPv4 connectivity, it doesn’t show that address. Use another page like [ip4.me](http://ip4.me/). Compare the address you get with the one displayed in your router configuration. If it’s the same, you can set up port forwarding to enable incoming IPv4 connections.